# .Flac files on Ipod Classic?

Tags: 13.10, music

I'm super new to Linux, being a Windows user my whole life, and I'm really trying to learn as much as I can.  When I made the switch, I took my 42+ GB collection of music (Previously handled in Itunes) with me, with over 500 songs in .wav format.  Wanting tag support, I've converted all of these files to .flac successfully through Soundconverter, but just now found out that my Ipod Classic won't play .flac files!

So, now I'm looking for a way to get these files onto my Ipod and play them.  I don't care if I have to update its firmware, convert these .flac files to Apple Lossless or any other method, whether through a program or the terminal, all I care about is I want to retain tag support and have them in a lossless format.  Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to convert your .flac files to apple loseless format (ALAC) to be able to play them with your ipod. You'll also be able to play your alac files using music player available on Ubuntu.

Here is [explanations](http://linuxg.net/convert-flac-to-alac-and-alac-to-flac-from-the-command-line/) to convert flac files to alac files.

If you've a lot of files to convert, it can be a good idea to write a script that will convert your files. If you need help for that, ask a new question.